# Python Crash Course - Chapter 9 - eric.privileges.show_privileges()

Tags: python

I'm currently studying Python Crash Course and I'm on chapter 9, Classes.  I'm working through one the of problems and went to the books website to get the solution.  I understand how most of it works except one line of code.  Here is the whole code:

```
class User():
    """Represent a simple user profile."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the user."""
        self.first_name = first_name.title()
        self.last_name = last_name.title()
        self.username = username
        self.email = email
        self.location = location.title()
        self.login_attempts = 0

    def describe_user(self):
        """Display a summary of the user's information."""
        print("\n" + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name)
        print("  Username: " + self.username)
        print("  Email: " + self.email)
        print("  Location: " + self.location)

    def greet_user(self):
        """Display a personalized greeting to the user."""
        print("\nWelcome back, " + self.username + "!")

    def increment_login_attempts(self):
        """Increment the value of login_attempts."""
        self.login_attempts += 1

    def reset_login_attempts(self):
        """Reset login_attempts to 0."""
        self.login_attempts = 0


class Admin(User):
    """A user with administrative privileges."""

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, username, email, location):
        """Initialize the admin."""
        super().__init__(first_name, last_name, username, email, location)

        # Initialize an empty set of privileges.
        self.privileges = Privileges()

class Privileges():
    """A class to store an admin's privileges."""

    def __init__(self, privileges=[]):
        self.privileges = privileges

    def show_privileges(self):
        print("\nPrivileges:")
        if self.privileges:
            for privilege in self.privileges:
                print("- " + privilege)
        else:
            print("- This user has no privileges.")


eric = Admin('eric', 'matthes', 'e_matthes', 'e_matthes@example.com', 'alaska')
eric.describe_user()

eric.privileges.show_privileges()

print("\nAdding privileges...")
eric_privileges = [
    'can reset passwords',
    'can moderate discussions',
    'can suspend accounts',
    ]
eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges
eric.privileges.show_privileges()
```

What is not clear to me is the `eric.privileges.privileges = eric_privileges` line.  I know it's pointing back to eric_privileges that contains a list.  But what is the eric.privileges.privileges part?  I think eric.privileges is the self.privileges.  But what about the second .privileges?

Comment: `eric` is a `User` object, which has a `.privileges` attribute: `eric.privileges`. That attribute is a `Privilege` object, which itself has a `privileges` attribute, which is a list.

Comment: Please understand that this site is dedicated to a greater cause than helping a single person such as yourself. The implication is that, when you ask a question, one expects it to be of lasting value and useful to future readers. Consider more meaningful, appropriate and general titles that address the problem at large. "Chapter 9 - eric.privileges"  is _not_ one of them. Something such as "understanding attribute assignment in __ init __ " is _much much_ clearer, and is basically what you are asking.

Comment: OK,  I'm new to this site.  I'm trying to learn Python by the book. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have this same book, but on Chapter 8 myself. I'll try my best to explain the code despite the comments.

`eric`, is an `object` of the Admin `class`, which `inherits` from User. Every administrator has a set of privileges, which is a `class` that contains a `list`.

This code:

```
eric.privileges
```

you call privileges which is located in the `admin`class(eric is an `object` of Admin, after all), it's an attribute of the Admin class.

This code:

```
.privileges
```

Right after the first privileges, is accessing the `list` in the privilege `class`, and he's assigned a `list`.

Think of the second call to privileges as a gateway to the privileges list which is in the Privileges class, from Admin. The book probably doesn't want to cover more in depth, but the author could have declared them as private with `_` and placed a setter in the Admin class.